# how to random generate a sequence of list that are unobserved before in python 3

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, random

Assume I have the code in Python 3

```
X, Y, Z = 10, 20, 30
data = [[1,3,6],[8,15,29],[8,9,19]] # observe data
```

Then how can I random generate `n` (not very large) data elements that are not in the `data`.

Condition: the element `[a,b,c]` must be not in `data` and `0<a<X`, `0<b<Y`, `0<c<Z`

`[1,3,5]` is good since it is not in `data` and its element satisfy the Condition

`[11,3,6]` is bad since it does not satisfy the Condition, `11>10`

For example, when `n=4`, I want a list of element that are not duplicate

```
newdata = [[1,6,6],[8,17,25],[2,6,11], [4,6,12]]
```

Comment: Sounds like an interesting problem, can you also include a reasonable coding attempt to start with?

Comment: @davedwards, I am still thinking. My method is to use brute force technique. such as generate all possible of elements and then select randomly the `n` elements that are not in the `data`. But it is not efficient.

Comment: That might work but yeah brute force is not always efficient. Maybe something like generate `random.randint(0, X)` and check that the result is not in the `data` list, if not, then add to the newdata list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
from random import randint

X, Y, Z = 10, 20, 30
data = [[1,3,6],[8,15,29],[8,9,19]]
n = 4

newdata = set()

for i in range(n):
    while True:
    l = [randint(1, X), randint(1, Y), randint(1, Z)]
    if l not in data:
        newdata.add(tuple(l))
        break

print(newdata)
```

Example result:

```
newdata = [(9, 9, 11), (10, 10, 4), (7, 6, 23), (2, 10, 4)]
```

Comment: This will generate too few samples if `l in data` as it breaks the loop nevertheless. The `break` should be placed inside the `if` block.

Comment: Also it doesn't deal with uniqueness of the generated samples, i.e. this approach allows duplicates. This requires another check `l not in newdata` so I'd highly recommend to use a set for both `data` and `newdata` to speed up membership tests.

Comment: @a_guest, that is a good point.  It seems that this approach allows duplicates.

Comment: @davedwards You still need to check `l not in newdata` as well (or instead of the `for` loop do `while len(newdata) < n`). Right now there are no duplicates allowed but it will generate too few samples in case duplicates are generated. Also I recommend converting `data` to a `set` before running the algorithm to improve membership testing. And you can create `l` as a `tuple` right from the beginning that saves an extra conversion.

Answer (score 0):

It took a small effort, but this seems to work:

```
from random import *
from pprint import pprint

X, Y, Z = 10, 20, 30
data = [[1,3,6],[8,15,29],[8,9,19]]

while 1:
    newData = []
    try: n = int(input("How many lists do you want: "))
    except:
        print("Please enter an integer.\n")
        continue
    for i in range(n):
        newList = [randrange(1, X), randrange(1, Y), randrange(1, Z)]
        while (newList in data) or (newList in newData):
            newList = [randrange(1, X), randrange(1, Y), randrange(1, Z)]
        newData.append(newList)
    pprint(newData)
```

This works by creating an empty list, getting a value for n, then entering a loop of exactly n iterations. It then creates a new list that satisfies the requirements. If the new list is in the observed data list, it just does it again and again until it isn't in the data. Then it adds this data to the output list and repeats the process until the for loop breaks (after n iterations).

There may be a better way of doing it, but this does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In case `X, Y, Z` are not too large you can just create all possible combinations and then sample from this pool:

```
import itertools as it
import random

x, y, z = 10, 20, 30
pool = it.product(range(x), range(y), range(z))
data = [(1, 3, 6), (8, 15, 29), (8, 9, 19)]
pool = set(pool) - set(data)
n = 4
newdata = random.sample(pool, n)
```

Answer (score 0):

For higher performance you can use Numpy and the fact that the tuples can be converted to integer and back by simply enumerating them (as `z, y, x` gets enumerated):

```
import numpy as np

x, y, z = 100, 200, 300
n = 1000

data = [[1,3,6],[8,15,29],[8,9,19]]
forbidden = [i[0]*y*z + i[1]*z + i[2] for i in data]
pool = np.arange(x*y*z)
mask = np.ones(pool.size, dtype=bool)
mask[forbidden] = False
pool = pool[mask]
newdata = np.random.choice(pool, n, replace=False)
newdata = [(i // (y*z), i // z, i % z) for i in newdata]
```